# Setting up the environment for Qt usage

Tags: qt

Before I start explaining the problem - yes I looked in the Qt forums and website before coming here.

I downloaded and installed the Qt libraries and the IDE. After the installation I got the following:

http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/04/59/4ce35a1b489a0459.png

after I clicked on the command prompt icon I got the following:
http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/79/13/0d46b97041da7913.jpg

When I type "vcvarsall.bat" I get and invalid command error. I am obviously doing something wrong, question is - what exactly?

Comment: What is the error exactly? "Invalid command"?

Comment: Hello, Luca! The exact message is: "'vcvarsall.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: It simply means it is not in the path it seems. Did you look for that batch file?

Comment: I did look for it right now, and there is a bunch of folders in the folder in which the file is being searched. Maybe it is in one of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error simply means that `vcvarsall.bat` is not in a folder that is listed in your `PATH` environment variable. You can fix that in two ways.

- [You can set your `PATH` environment variable to include the folder where vcvarsall.bat is located.](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20set%20path%20environment%20variable&aq=f&oq=windows%20set%20path%20environment%20variable&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- You can `cd` into the folder where `vcvarsall.bat` is located and call `vcvarsall.bat` from there.

In my case (and by default), `vcvarsall.bat` is located in the following directory:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`

**EDIT:** For Visual Studio 2017, the location has changed. It is now at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: I want to thank Fred for giving this answer. It cleared things up.

EDIT: I was being stupid and didn't include the libraries in the installation so it is only normal that I couldn't work with the IDE properly.

Comment: And for the Pro version its in a slightly different path: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build

Comment: The 2019 community path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat